# How does AWS EBS cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My server is allocated with 200GB EBS and even though the server is fairly quiet, I still got a charge of $38.15 for the last month. I have gone over AWS explanation but still confused about the formula

```
Example from AWS: ($0.10 * 2000GB * 43,200 seconds / (86,400 seconds/day * 30)) = $3.33
My case (Sydney): ($0.12 * 200GB * 86,400 / (86,400 * 30)) = $0.8
```

My bill last month

[image]

How EBS cost is actually calculated?

Comment: Can I know the reason why this question got down vote?

Comment: Their example is for 12 hours, not for an entire month.

Comment: I guess down vote is because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Your charge as explained in your case would be true if you provision your EBS for 86,400 seconds in the month.

You are charged because you used many time more than 86,400 seconds that month

The charge in AWS's example means that it will cost $3.33 for 43,200 seconds of using 2000Gb